# Java UnsupportedAudioFileException

Tags: java, javasound

I'm reading codec file and converting to mp3/wav file using Java and Java Sound but getting the following Error.

### Error

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: file is not a supported file type
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(AudioSystem.java:1076)
at test.postingstackOverflow.main(postingstackOverflow.java:29)
```

### Code

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;

/**
 *
 * @author shankar
 */
public class postingstackOverflow {


    public static void main(String args[]){

         AudioFileFormat inputFileFormat=null;
         javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat audioFormat =null;
         AudioInputStream encodedASI=null;
         AudioInputStream ais=null;

         try{

            inputFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(new File("/media/shankar/voip/Temp/JavaSound/1000.g711u"));
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/media/shankar/voip/Temp/JavaSound/1000.g711u"));
            audioFormat = ais.getFormat();
            encodedASI = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW, ais);

            int i = AudioSystem.write(encodedASI, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("/media/shankar/voip/Temp/JavaSound/converted.mp3"));

         }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

         }finally{

             try{
                    if(encodedASI!=null)
                        encodedASI.close();

                    if(ais!=null)
                        ais.close();
                    if(encodedASI!=null)
                        encodedASI.close();
                }catch(Exception expClose){
                    expClose.printStackTrace();
                }
       }//end finally
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how solve reading a μ-law file?

Comment: See the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) sections on **Service Provider Interface**, **Java Sound Capabilities** & **MP3 decoding support** ..

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question. Is it fair to say that a simpler version would be to write something that plays back a ulaw source? If you can play back the ulaw source (as a Clip or SourceDataLine), then the problem is in the conversion. If you can't, then the problem is in reading the ulaw file. It could be helpful to narrow things down in this way.

Comment: thanks for your reply Mr Phil Freihofner. i want convert ulaw to wav or mp3 format.  no play back required.

Comment: Writing `.mp3` is definitely not supported out of the box by Java. So writing `.wav` is a much safer bet. That said, μ-law is an encoding (like PCM), not a file format. Your file format seems to be `.g711u` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.711#.CE.BC-Law). And that file format is definitely not supported by Java out of the box, either. Perhaps renaming the file to `.au` helps. If none of that works, you might want to try [FFSampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/), if you're on Windows/OSX. It might support `.g711u`. No promises though.